# icalendar AssertionError: VTIMEZONEs sub-components' DTSTART must be of type datetime, not date

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, icalendar, assertion

When I run this code in Python 3.75, vscode:

```
from icalendar import Calendar 
import requests
SkeddaBridgeURL = 'https://bridgeartspace.skedda.com/ical?key=457bda7'
f=requests.get(SkeddaBridgeURL)
c = Calendar.from_ical(f.text)
```

I get this error:

```
VTIMEZONEs sub-components' DTSTART must be of type datetime, not date
  File "/Users/jeff/Scrape/Code/skedda.py", line 6, in <module>
    c = Calendar.from_ical(f.text)
```

But when I run this URL through the ical validator at https://icalendar.org/validator.html, I get no errors.

I don't feel qualified to call this a bug, but maybe it is!

One way I have tried to deal with this is to suppress Assertion Errors by a startup flag as:
`python 3 -Oc "Assert False"`

But I fail to see how to set this as a flag in VSCode, which I am also learning.

Furthermore, running the debugger on this code, having installed `icalendar` via pip3, I cannot step into the code, or modify it.  Will I need to figure out how to download the entire module from github and go delete the assertion?

Comment: what error do you get running it outside VSC?

Comment: Same error on the command line, except when I add the -Oc "Assert False" flag.

Comment: It looks like the data is indeed defective, which means the validator is, too.  Suppressing assertion exceptions might or might not work.  You could fix up the data after downloading it and before converting it.  It's just a text file with a format documented in RFCs 2445 and 5545, so it shouldn't be too hard to tweak in Python.  Or you could try the ics library instead of icalendar and see if it is more forgiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A timezone daylight saving change begins at a DATE & TIME not just on a day so it must be a DATE-TIME not a DATE.    From https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-6-5-time-zone-component.html

> The mandatory "DTSTART" property gives the effective onset date and
> local time for the time zone sub-component definition. "DTSTART" in
> this usage MUST be specified as a date with a local time value.

The various validators do not pick up everything in my experience, so i try to check with all I can find. In addition, the various major calendar applications do not all support everything in the RFC5545 specification. ( Eg: google calendar didnt do recurring BYHOUR last I checked.) Therefore it is best to also do testing with the major calendar applications as well.   Google used to be very finicky about files without always a good message.